# tkinter window not opening no matter what

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, terminal, window

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, Text
import os

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=700, width=700, bg="#aa0505")
canvas.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I tried reinstalling python, pip, tkinter, I even switched to a different ide because of this problem.

ps I was originally using vs code but then I thought i might switch to pycharm

Comment: Is there any log or err trace? I run this code normally on PyCharm

Comment: This code works fine for me on OSX with python 3.9.13.

Comment: Welcome to SO! [Here's how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541). Can you please read it and apply what you learn to improve your question? (If you have no stack trace, that's ok) Please also read [ask] and describe your problem _before_ showing code.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. `tkinter` is part of python so I don't know what it means to reinstall it. Did you check that the window isn't being opened bellow your ide?

Comment: Do not Copied and pasted into IDLE.  Just type code And see what happened.